# Android : Acces parent fragment function from child fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have a ***Parent Fragment*** in an ***activity*** and have a ***Child Fragment*** in ***Parent Fragment***. The NavGraphs of the two Fragments are ***different***. I want to access the function in the ***Parent Fragment*** from the ***Child Fragment***, but the application crashes. How can I do it?

**Child Fragment:**

```
class ProfilinMenu : Fragment(){

private var _binding : FragmentProfilinMenuBinding? = null
private val profilinmenubinding get() =  _binding!!

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    _binding = FragmentProfilinMenuBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)


    (parentFragment as Parent).changeName() // this is for access parent


    return profilinmenubinding.root
}}
```

**Parent Fragment:**

```
public class Parent : Fragment() {

private var _binding : FragmentParentBinding? = null
private val parentBinding get() = _binding!!
private var instance: Parent? = null


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {

    _binding = FragmentParentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val view = parentBinding.root

  
    return view
}

public fun changeName(){
    parentBinding.profilinIsmin.text = "Merhaba"
}
```

Comment: you can use viewmodel to do the communication part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getParentFragment();
ParentFragment parent = (ParentFragment) navHostFragment.getParentFragment();
parent.changeName()
```